# Why do different classes take the same amount of memory?

Tags: python, optimization

Why does foo not take more memory if it has another variable?

```
class Foo():
  a = 1
  b = 1

class Bar():
  a = 1

import sys

foo = Foo()
print(sys.getsizeof(foo))  # 56
bar = Bar()
print(sys.getsizeof(bar))  # 56
```

Comment: the methods are not saved in the object itself, if it was, all would be duplicate in all instances,

Comment: Methods aren't stored with objects, but with the type of the object.

Comment: That is, each object maintains a reference to its type, and the method is accessed via the type. `foo.bar` is really just shorthand for `Foo.bar.__get__(foo, Foo)`.

Comment: It wouldn't be that weird: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, methods are stored with the type of the object, not the object itself.

However, you'll notice that if you ask for the class sizes, they are equal as well.

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(Foo)
1064
>>> sys.getsizeof(Bar)
1064
```

Each class object has a `__dict__` attribute that stores references to its methods and other attributes.

```
>>> Foo.__dict__['why_does_this_not_use_take_memory']
<function Foo.why_does_this_not_use_take_memory at 0x103609ef0>
```

However, `sys.getsizeof` doesn't recurse into that `dict`; it only returns the memory used by the `class` object itself, not including objects that you can *reach* via the `class` and its attributes.

---

Each method is a class attribute. Without going too much into the descriptor protocol, in general, something like `foo.why_does_this_not_use_take_memory` is really just shorthand for

```
Foo.why_does_this_not_use_take_memory.__get__(foo, Foo)
```

That is, the `function`-valued attribute is retrieved, but then its `__get__` method is called to return a `method` object specific to `foo`. The `method` is essentially just a wrapper around the function which, when called, passes `foo` and its own arguments to `Foo.why_does_this_not_use_take_memory` (which is how `self` gets bound to `foo`).

Comment: In addition to this excellent answer, I’d recommend [Pympler](https://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/) to get detailed info about the memory size of Python objects. Example usage in the link. A bit more detailed blogpost about object memory usage and an intro to accounting class memory size [here](https://www.scrygroup.com/tutorial/2018-09-04/find-size-of-python-object/).